# Fastest way to copy a blittable struct to an unmanaged memory location (IntPtr)

Tags: c#, performance, intptr

I have a function similar to the following:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public void SetVariable<T>(T newValue) where T : struct {
    // I know by this point that T is blittable (i.e. only unmanaged value types)

    // varPtr is a void*, and is where I want to copy newValue to
    *varPtr = newValue; // This won't work, but is basically what I want to do
}
```

I saw Marshal.StructureToIntPtr(), but it seems quite slow, and this is performance-sensitive code. If I knew the type `T` I could just declare `varPtr` as a `T*`, but... Well, I don't.

Either way, I'm after the fastest possible way to do this. 'Safety' is not a concern: By this point in the code, I know that the size of the struct `T` will fit exactly in to the memory pointed to by `varPtr`.

Comment: Various system DLLs have `memcpy` and similar functions.  Declare one parameter as `IntPtr`, the other as `ref T`, pass the size in bytes, and be happy.

Comment: Is memcpy still the fastest, despite the P/Invoke stuff?

Comment: There won't be much p/invoke overhead for a call like this, provided the structure is directly blittable.  But do compare it to `Marshal.StructureToPtr`

Comment: You could also write an "unsafe" loop in C# using `byte*` for source and destination, but unless the object is really small, `memcpy` or `CopyMemory` should be faster than single-byte copies... at least until the JIT starts recognizing memcpy-like loops in MSIL.  (It's a very common thing for optimizing C and C++ compilers to recognize roll-your-own memcpy and substitute the faster platform version)

Comment: @Claus: How is this question not about performance?

Comment: @BenVoigt The objects in question are between 4 and 64 bytes each... Is that small enough to hand-copy, do you think?

Comment: At the 4-16 end, I definitely expect the cost of single byte copies to be less than function-call overhead.  16-64, you'd need to measure.  How slow is `Marshal` for this exactly?  If I were you, I'd implement all 3 (`Marshal.StructureToPtr`, p/invoke `memcpy` or `CopyMemory`, and `byte*` loop) and see which is faster on your platform.

Comment: BTW if the pointers are aligned, you can use `Int32*` or `Int64*` loop instead.  The savings should even pay for a runtime test that the size is a multiple of 4 or 8.

Comment: @BenVoigt I find it to ambiguous to this type of questions, where a more explicit code-solution is required. Performance should be A versus B, or about optimizations of a existing solution. If you disagree, feel free to revert the change. (And in general, I find tags like performance are really to ambiguous for Stack Overflow)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your interesting pointers (pun intended, hurr hurr). I added an answer after doing some testing.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen-MSFT: I believe this is optimization of an existing solution, namely `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One answer is to reimplement native memcpy instead in C#, making use of the same optimizing tricks that native memcpy attempts to do. You can see Microsoft doing this in their own source. See the [Buffer.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/buffer.cs.html#0d691e54a9fdddc3) file in the Microsoft Reference Source:

```
     // This is tricky to get right AND fast, so lets make it useful for the whole Fx.
     // E.g. System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime!WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.MemCopy uses it.
     internal unsafe static void Memcpy(byte* dest, byte* src, int len) {

        // This is portable version of memcpy. It mirrors what the hand optimized assembly versions of memcpy typically do.
        // Ideally, we would just use the cpblk IL instruction here. Unfortunately, cpblk IL instruction is not as efficient as
        // possible yet and so we have this implementation here for now.

        switch (len)
        {
        case 0:
            return;
        case 1:
            *dest = *src;
            return;
        case 2:
            *(short *)dest = *(short *)src;
            return;
        case 3:
            *(short *)dest = *(short *)src;
            *(dest + 2) = *(src + 2);
            return;
        case 4:
            *(int *)dest = *(int *)src;
            return;
        ...
```

Its interesting to note that they natively implement memcpy for all sizes up to 512; most of the sizes use pointer aliasing tricks to get the VM to emit instructions that operate on differing sizes. Only at 512 do they finally drop into invoking the native memcpy:

```
        // P/Invoke into the native version for large lengths
        if (len >= 512)
        {
            _Memcpy(dest, src, len);
            return;
        }
```

Presumably, native memcpy is even faster since it can be hand optimized to use SSE/MMX instructions to perform the copy.

Comment: Wow, that Buffer.cs hacky stuff is quite amazing, and now I really have to study it and try to understand, haha :). And yes, I really wish we'd get SSE and better support for this stuff soon in C#.

Comment: I wonder whether pointer alignment or lack thereof has much impact.

Answer (score 2):

As per BenVoigt's suggestion, I tried a few options. For all these tests I compiled with Any CPU architecture, on a standard VS2013 Release build, and ran the test outside of the IDE. Before each test was measured, the methods `DoTestA()` and `DoTestB()` were run multiple times to allow the JIT warmup.

---

First, I compared `Marshal.StructToPtr` to a byte-by-byte loop with various struct sizes. I've shown the code below using a `SixtyFourByteStruct`:

```
private unsafe static void DoTestA() {
    fixed (SixtyFourByteStruct* fixedStruct = &structToCopy) {
        byte* structStart = (byte*) fixedStruct;
        byte* targetStart = (byte*) unmanagedTarget;
        for (byte* structPtr = structStart, targetPtr = targetStart; structPtr < structStart + sizeof(SixtyFourByteStruct); ++structPtr, ++targetPtr) {
            *targetPtr = *structPtr;
        }
    }
}

private static void DoTestB() {
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(structToCopy, unmanagedTarget, false);
}
```

And the results:

```
>>> 500000 repetitions >>> IN NANOSECONDS (1000ns = 0.001ms)
Method   Avg.         Min.         Max.         Jitter       Total
A        82ns         0ns          22,000ns     21,917ns     ! 41.017ms
B        137ns        0ns          38,700ns     38,562ns     ! 68.834ms
```

As you can see, the manual loop is faster (as I suspected). The results are similar for a sixteen-byte and four-byte struct, with the difference being more pronounced the smaller the struct goes.

---

So now, to try the manual copy vs using P/Invoke and memcpy:

```
private unsafe static void DoTestA() {
    fixed (FourByteStruct* fixedStruct = &structToCopy) {
        byte* structStart = (byte*) fixedStruct;
        byte* targetStart = (byte*) unmanagedTarget;
        for (byte* structPtr = structStart, targetPtr = targetStart; structPtr < structStart + sizeof(FourByteStruct); ++structPtr, ++targetPtr) {
            *targetPtr = *structPtr;
        }
    }
}

private unsafe static void DoTestB() {
    fixed (FourByteStruct* fixedStruct = &structToCopy) {
        memcpy(unmanagedTarget, (IntPtr) fixedStruct, new UIntPtr((uint) sizeof(FourByteStruct)));
    }
}

>>> 500000 repetitions >>> IN NANOSECONDS (1000ns = 0.001ms)
Method   Avg.         Min.         Max.         Jitter       Total
A        61ns         0ns          28,000ns     27,938ns     ! 30.736ms
B        84ns         0ns          45,900ns     45,815ns     ! 42.216ms
```

So, it seems that the manual copy is still better in my case. Like before, the results were pretty similar for 4/16/64 byte structs (though the gap was <10ns for 64-byte size).

---

It occurred to me that I was only testing structures that fit on a cache line (I have a standard x86_64 CPU). So I tried a 128-byte structure, and it swung the balance in the favour of memcpy:

```
>>> 500000 repetitions >>> IN NANOSECONDS (1000ns = 0.001ms)
Method   Avg.         Min.         Max.         Jitter       Total
A        104ns        0ns          48,300ns     48,195ns     ! 52.150ms
B        84ns         0ns          38,400ns     38,315ns     ! 42.284ms
```

---

Anyway, the conclusion to all that is that **the byte-by-byte copy seems the fastest** for any struct of size <=64 bytes on an x86_64 CPU on my machine. Take it as you will (and maybe someone will spot an inefficiency in my code anyway).

Comment: You may want to invoke those test methods once outside of your timing loop to ensure that they are JITed; that might explain the 500% jitter you're seeing.

Comment: @antiduh See the top of my answer, I ran each one many times before timing them. It's more likely that the jitter is GC (seems unlikely though) or perhaps just the OS scheduling the thread?

Comment: Just one note, I meant to use `ref structToCopy` when invoking `memcpy`, and let p/invoke do the pinning.  Not actually sure whether that would make any difference in performance.  Anyway, this lines up with my expectation, sizes under 16 bytes strongly favor manual loop, very large structures favor `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI. I'm posting how I leveraged [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620105/1618433) for others' benefit as there's a twist when accessing the method via reflection because it's overloaded.

```
public static class Buffer
{
    public unsafe delegate void MemcpyDelegate(byte* dest, byte* src, int len);

    public static readonly MemcpyDelegate Memcpy;
    static Buffer()
    {
        var methods = typeof (System.Buffer).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Where(m=>m.Name == "Memcpy");
        var memcpy = methods.First(mi => mi.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(new[] {typeof (byte*), typeof (byte*), typeof (int)}));
        Memcpy = (MemcpyDelegate) memcpy.CreateDelegate(typeof (MemcpyDelegate));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static unsafe void MemcpyExample()
{
     int src = 12345;
     int dst = 0;
     Buffer.Memcpy((byte*) &dst, (byte*) &src, sizeof (int));
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(dst==12345);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   public void SetVariable<T>(T newValue) where T : struct
```

You cannot use generics to accomplish this the fast way.  The compiler doesn't take your pretty blue eyes as a guarantee that T is actually blittable, the constraint isn't good enough.  You should use overloads:

```
    public unsafe void SetVariable(int newValue) {
        *(int*)varPtr = newValue;
    }
    public unsafe void SetVariable(double newValue) {
        *(double*)varPtr = newValue;
    }
    public unsafe void SetVariable(Point newValue) {
        *(Point*)varPtr = newValue;
    }
    // etc...
```

Which might be inconvenient, but blindingly fast.  It compiles to single MOV instruction with no method call overhead in Release mode.  The fastest it could be.

And the back-up case, the profiler will tell you when you need to overload:

```
    public unsafe void SetVariable<T>(T newValue) {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(newValue, (IntPtr)varPtr, false);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with using custom overloads is that implies I know what T is at compile time... Which sorta defeats the point of generics (and I'm not just being idealistic, I really don't know T at compile time, I just have a good idea of it).

Comment: Hmya, who would ever bother with C# if I-dont-know-the-type languages like Python or Ruby could be just as fast.

Comment: I guess, it would be people who like type safety in a productive language!

Comment: I already said in the original question: "If I knew the type `T` I could just declare `varPtr` as a `T*`, but... Well, I don't." So this answer is no good to me, and therefore didn't answer my actual question (which was for a faster alternative to `StructureToPtr`). Thankfully Ben Voigt and others have already helped pretty well.