# Ensuring Endian-Independent Copy of primitives

Tags: c#, pointers, endianness

```
public unsafe void WriteInt64(long value) //C# Code
    {
        fixed (byte* ptr = m_buffer)
        {
            *(long*)(ptr)   = value;
        }
    }
```

In the above code, the value is being directly assigned to the pointer. I wonder if this code is any way achieving endian-independent code or if not, how its correct?

Another way to put this is
Over here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24620105/413306, how the pointer copy in memcpy method is achieving endian-independent code?

Comment: You need to check system/cpu-dependent macros defining its endian, and convert them to your favorite endian on your own.

Comment: It's not endian-independent, but that's often not a goal in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can really do is look at [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Indicates the byte order ("endianness") in which data is stored in
>   this computer architecture.

And pass in a desired endian state to your function, who knows where your `m_buffer` is ending up on what machine.

If the desired state and your current architecture different you are going to have to switch